# MYSQL inner join and derived tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries that work separately, but can't figure out how to combine them into one.

The first calculates the availability of a piece of plant, like so:

```
SELECT *, 
(off_time - on_time)/(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('x') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('y')) AS A
FROM(
 SELECT equipment_id,
  IF(time_on < 'x', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('x'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_on)) AS on_time,
   (CASE  
    WHEN (time_off IS NULL) THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
    WHEN (time_off > 'y') THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('y')
    ELSE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_off)
   END) AS off_time
  FROM r) AS T
GROUP BY equipment_id
```

But I only want to show plant identified as being available for service which is stored in a separate table so I figure I have to use a JOIN, something like:

```
SELECT r.equipment_id, r.time_on, r.time_off, i.in_service
FROM r
INNER JOIN i
ON r.equipment_id=i.equipment_id
```

However, my attempts to combine the two result in failure.  I'm self taught and very new to this so any help, comments or even just some critique on my queries is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can join it like this.

```
SELECT
  *,
  ((off_time - on_time)/(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('x') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('y'))) AS A
FROM (SELECT
    r.equipment_id,
    i.in_service,
    IF(time_on < 'x', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('x'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_on)) AS on_time,
    (CASE WHEN (time_off IS NULL) THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) WHEN (time_off > 'y') THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('y') ELSE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_off) END) AS off_time
      FROM r
    left join i
      ON r.equipment_id = i.equipment_id) AS T
GROUP BY equipment_id
```

Comment: As with Minesh's suggestion, I get an error (1052) Column 'equipment_id' in field list is ambiguous.  Thank you for taking the time  :)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much, been struggling with that all morning!   :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, below is the SQL you are looking for:

```
SELECT *, 
(off_time - on_time)/(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('x') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('y')) AS A, i.in_service
FROM(
 SELECT equipment_id,
  IF(time_on < 'x', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('x'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_on)) AS on_time,
   (CASE  
    WHEN (time_off IS NULL) THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
    WHEN (time_off > 'y') THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('y')
    ELSE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_off)
   END) AS off_time
  FROM r) AS T 
INNER JOIN i
ON T.equipment_id=i.equipment_id
GROUP BY T.equipment_id
```

Comment: Thanks Minesh, but it gives me an error (1052) Column 'equipment_id' in field list is ambiguous, don't really understand what that means.

Comment: corrected that , you need to use table alias in Group By clause